# Apps using Webkit, like Foliate, Wike, Caveliar or GNOME Web do not show content Ubuntu 22.04 with NVIDIA graphics

Tags: 22.04, snap, flatpak

This only seems to happen to snaps and flatpaks (not even AppImages). Several apps like Wike, Foliate, Cavalier (Snaps), Wike-Flatpak, and even GNOME Web (Flatpak) run but then show no content / do anything. The app doesn't throw any error, 404, or anything else. Moneta at least indicates you can't connect to the server. As far as I see, permissions are correctly set, and setting all of them on yields no result. This very same app worked fine in regular Ubuntu releases (23.04, 23.10...).

Some examples:

Foliate (Snap). Loads the book but no content shown.
[image]

Wike Wikipedia reader (Snap and Flatpak) allows search queries and history, but nothing shows up. It does not integrate with GNOME Shell search, as it should, either.

[image]

Tangram web browser (Flatpak). The same issue. The same with GNOME Web flatpak.

[image]

PS: I checked the terminal. There seems to be some permission or access issue with KMS or anything else. Excuse the Spanish captions. 'Falló al abrir el archivo' -> Failed to open file. 'Permiso denegado' -> Permission denied.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post terminal output messages as text instead of images.

Comment: Yes! I'll do so in future questions. Worked great. Thank you so much Archisman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=259644) with NVidia graphics cards.

The workaround is to run the apps with the environment variable `WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1`.

### Flatpak

For Foliate, run the command

```
flatpak run --env=WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1 com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate
```

For Wike,

```
flatpak run --env=WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1 com.github.hugolabe.wike
```

In Foliate particularly, sometimes the sidebar is not displatyed if the locale is not set to be English. That can be done with the environment variable `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`.

```
flatpak run --env=WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1 --env=LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate
```

To make this change permanent when you open the apps with the GUI, you can add the environment variables in the Flatseal app.

[image: Flatseal]

Source: https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues/1115#issuecomment-1809480892

### Snap/Debian packages

You can add the environment variable `WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1` to `/etc/environment`, and reboot for the changes to take effect.